# Input print to score system

Tags: python, input, blob, rgb, simplecv

I have code that compares the x y coordinates with another and prints the RGB values to the terminal. How can I use the RGB values as input for a scoring system?

```
img = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/DartProj/DartConvert/dart1blob.jpg')
blobs = img.findBlobs()
first_blob = blobs[0] if blobs else None
if first_blob:
    pixcol = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/DartProj/Score/ColourScoreBoard.jpg')
    colrgb =  pixcol[first_blob.x, first_blob.y]
print colrgb
```

The code above prints the RGB values to the terminal, eg. (63.0, 71.0, 204.0) - a shade of blue. How can I make that particular RGB value equal a score of 20 (and other RGB values to other scores).

Any help, guidance, links etc would be appreciated, beginner here.

Comment: What is the score meant to represent and how can these rgb values represent a higher score than others? Is one colour weighted higher than others?

Comment: I'm scoring a dartboard, each segment is filled with a different colour and in return I need to make these colours equal the score of the segment.

Comment: Is every single segment a different colour?

Comment: Mostly, except for between 1 and 20 where there are two segments for the single score. I have code which gets the xy coordinates of the thrown dart, compares it to the color segments scoring image and returns the color value of the xy coordinates. I need to allocate a score to each color value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a mapping between the rgb tuples and the score. Below is an example, you'd have to implement the full mapping with the rgb values you know you have on your board.

```
rgbmap = { (255, 255, 255): 60, (0, 0, 0): 20, (0, 0, 255): 2}

def getscoreforrgb(rgb):
    return rgbmap[rgb]

print "score for 255, 255, 255 is ", rgbmap[(255, 255, 255)]
print "score for 0, 0, 0 is ", getscoreforrgb((0, 0, 0))
```

You can take advantage of the fact a tuple is hashable and use it as a dictionary key. You can wrap it in a function or just access the dict directly, up to you (both methods shown).

Obviously you get an exception if that tuple has no entry in the map but you'd have to wrap the code in a try/except.

Comment: How do I input the rgb values of the dart automatically?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the rgb value of the board?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to code, not sure how to ask the right questions yet. How do I compare colrgb(from my code above) to the rgb value of the board?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `simplecv` library unfortunately. From your code it looks like you grab the rgb value from the board in the `colrgb` variable. So you would need to pass that to the mapping function.

Comment: The first thing you need to do however is get a list of all the possible rgb values in your board and write the mapping dict (what I've called rgbmap). I can't know all the rgb values on your board and what scores are associated with them. So you'll have to write the mapping yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77947/discussion-between-paul-rooney-and-owen-lyons).

Comment: Thank you, the only part I'm missing is how to pass the rgb values of the variable colrgb to the rgbmap.

Comment: click on the chat link

Answer (score 1):

Well you could define some function that takes in a rgb value as a paramter and returns a score for that value through some logic that you define.

For example:

```
def RGBtoScore(rgb):
    score = #insert your logic here.
    return score
```

You can access the rgb values like so:

```
rgb[0] #red
rgb[1] #green
rgb[2] #blue
```

My answer is not very specific because your question was rather vague. if you comment on this post, I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I aim to write a darts scoring software in which each segment of the board is a different rgb value, there are 82 segments on a dartboard, each would represent 1 - 20, plus the doubles and triples, and the 25 and the bullseye.  I can obtain the rgb value of one particular segment (I'm focusing on socring one segment right now) and would like to be able to return this value as the score of 13.

Comment: ok, you would use if statements to achieve this. http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html